# BeanShell Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beanshell

I am converting my selenium code to run through beanshell, Variable string execode contains all importe libraries statements and string av contains the code to execute. Although some void functions of selenium import class are working like check below in code the method "getTagName();" is working but the only void method now working is "sendKeys();":

```
Interpreter abc= (Interpreter) new bsh.Interpreter();
abc.set("driver", driver);
String av="WebElement us =driver.findElement(By.name(\"q\"));\n" +
        "+us.sendKeys();\n" +
"System.out.print(\"GET: \"+us.getTagName());"; 
abc.eval(execode+av);
```

Error receiving:

> > Error in method invocation: Method sendKeys() not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement' : at Line: 30 :

May someone know what's going wrong, why only sendKeys(); not working.

Comment: Is your question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with your classpath.

You are using `org.openqa.selenium.remote` package from `selenium-remote-driver...jar` instead of using `selenium.api...jar`. I checked that [RemoteWebElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-) has `sendKeys()`.

However, a version of your jar file is an old one which doesn't have this method. Try to add both jars to your's project classpath, and also check if their versions are the last.

Comment: But if I execute this code directly without beanshell with same libraries then it works, even in beanshell interpreter most of functions of same selenium class are working except sendKeys();

Comment: @A.Aleem11 exception shows that this method isn't presented for this class. Thus, something is completely different with executing without BeanShell.